# Why does #warning in VS2013 is producing an error?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, directive

I am using Visual Studio 2013, with Resharper 8.2.
I must be missing something here. I have added `#warning` to the code and it failed the build.

[image]

Question is why? isn't that's what `#error` is for?

Comment: Have you set `Treat Warnings as errors` somewhere in your project?

Comment: Why aren't you using the #TODO option for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect you have set the ["treat warnings as errors"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/406xhdz3.aspx) flag in your project build properties.

You can either remove that flag, or set it to only treat *specific* warnings as errors.

Comment: 27 seconds faster. damn

Answer (score 1):

Do you have "Treat warnings as errors" set in the Build properties of your project?

Comment: Thanks AZ. I have +1 as a second place prize